# Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 + bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, galaxy-tab

My problem is that bootstrap navbar breaks in two rows on Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 device which means it doesn't fit on device width (1280x800px). I used android default browser.
At the same time it looks good on all emulators and responsive design testers I've tried and fits in one row.
Media queries are:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
 .nav > li > a {
  padding: 13px 30px 10px;
 }
}
```

http://www.hemodialysis-krk.com

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, Bootstrap doesn't officially support the non-Chrome Android "Browser" app, primarily because it's super-buggy.

Comment: Tnx.I'll try in Chrome browser and report back.